# LNK2019 Unresolved Externals

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have some test code:

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void Foo(int iBar);

#endif FOO_H
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

void Foo(int iBar)
{
    // Do nothing...
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    Foo(1);

    return 0;
}
```

When I build the above code in VS2010 I get a linker error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl Foo(int)" (?Foo@@YAXH@Z) referenced in function _main

I can't figure out why my Foo() function would be unresolved at link-time. Can anybody give me some insight as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you link in foo.obj into the exe?

Comment: @n0rd: I use VS2010, so when I have my solution open I click _Build->Build Solution_ in the menu. Each project in a solution has various settings that can be altered regarding build paths, dependency declarations, etc. I haven't altered my build settings beyond where I want my executable generated.

Comment: are `main.cpp` and `foo.cpp` in the same project?

Comment: @n0rd: Yes, all the files mentioned are in the same project.

Comment: Are you sure `Foo` function is not defined in `foo.cpp` with `static` keyword? Anyway, run the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" go to you project directory, then under Debug or Release (depending on what you attempted to build) directory there should be foo.obj file. Run `dumpbin /symbols foo.obj` and check that a) `Foo` is exported, b) it has exactly the same mangled name as linker looks for (mentioned in error message). `dumpbin /symbols foo.obj | find "Foo"` might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some trial and error I got my code to successfully build by moving the definition code from foo.cpp into foo.h.

For whatever reason, it appears that foo.cpp wasn't being tied into foo.obj. I have global logging utility functions declared and defined in log.h and log.cpp respectively, just like I have in my test 'foo' files above, yet I have no problem compiling and linking them to my program. I wonder what I'm doing that has one link without issue, while the other doesn't recognize the cpp file.